# Resolving $i - 2 +|13-2i|$ to be in the form $a + b i$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Write $i - 2 +|13-2i|$ in the form $a + bi$, for real $a,b$.

I'm unsure how to reduce this. Wolfram Alpha tells me that this becomes the rational number $\sqrt{173}$ but I am unsure how to find that or why that is the case.

Comment: 1) $\sqrt{173}$ is most certainly not rational. 2) $i-2+\lvert 13-2i\rvert$ is most certainly not $\sqrt{173}$, because, since $\lvert\text{something}\rvert\in\Bbb R_+$, the imaginary part of the number you have is $1\cdot i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $|a+bi|$ is the magnitude (or 'length') of the imaginary number, found using the formula $$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Therefore we can rewrite this as \begin{align}i-2+|13-2i|&=i-2+\sqrt{13^2+(-2)^2}\\
&=i-2+\sqrt{169+4}\\
&=i-2+\sqrt{173}\\
&=\sqrt{173}-2+i\end{align}

So we have \begin{align}a&=\sqrt{173}-2\\
b&=1\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

we get$$i-2+\sqrt{169+4}=i+\sqrt{173}-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|13-2i| = \sqrt{13^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{173}$. This is the distance of the point $13 - 2i$ from the origin. Plot this point and draw thelines, you'll note it forms a triangle from which you can apply Pythagoras.

So $i - 2 +|13 - 2i| = i - 2 + \sqrt{173}$.

Answer (score 1):

One has $|13-2i|=\sqrt{13^2+2^2}=\sqrt{173}$ and so

$$-2+|13-2i|+i=-2+\sqrt{173}+i$$

Answer (score 1):

$$i-2+|13-2i|=i-2+\sqrt{13^2+(-2)^2}$$
$$=i-2+\sqrt{173}$$
$$=(\sqrt{173}-2)+i$$

Note: Remember that a complex numbers $a+bi$ is a vector in the complex plane. The 'length' of the vector $|a+bi|$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ which is known from Pythogoras' Theorem